# view flipper crashing when calling setDisplayChild(); on document ready with addjavascriptinterface, help please

Tags: android, jquery, webview, crash, viewflipper

i'm building an app project(my second ever) that, lets say, displays a splash loading screen whilst it awaits the second viewflipper layout with webview to load a webpage. the html web page on load calls a function in my android java that should `vf.setDisplayedChild(TWO);` but it doesn't!!! i have tested this with a toast instead of the afore mentioned function?! and this displays fine. but alas if i set it back to displayedchild my loading screen crashes and returns to my main.xml activity before restarting the activity with viewflipper and loops between crashing and reloading!

i suspect it has something to do with my vf controls in the oncreate function and the `vf.displaychild` call being in a public `javascriptinterface` class??!!! but dont have the knowledge to do more.

i have researched some sort of boolean change listener but dont think this is worth doing.

my code:

```
package com.......;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;


public class Webview  extends Activity {


    ViewFlipper vf;
    private final int ONE = 0;
    private final int TWO = 1;
        private WebView webView;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            setContentView(R.layout.vf);

            vf=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);    
            vf.addView(View.inflate(this, R.layout.load, null), ONE);
            vf.addView(View.inflate(this, R.layout.webview, null), TWO);
                vf.setDisplayedChild(ONE);



            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSI(this), "android");
            webView.loadUrl("my wamp dir");

            //failsafe if not shown
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                    public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry There was a problem!\nPlease check your Data/WI-FI connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                    }
                }, 30000);




        }



        public class JSI
        {
            Context mContext;

            /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
            JSI(Context c) {
                mContext = c;
            }

        public void loaded()
        {

            vf.setDisplayedChild(TWO);
            //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Showing!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        }

    }
```

and of course the function is called in jquery/script ready function as:

```
android.loaded();
```

any help appreciated towards an answer!

EDIT-------------------------
have figured out the debugger and am getting an exception regarding : only a thread can access its set up views!

Answer (score 0):

AAAH i didnt know about `runOnUiThread()`
this sorted it!

```
public void Activated()
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                   vf.setDisplayedChild(TWO);
                }
            });
```

and just noticed i have forgotten to stop my handler delay executing, if statement variable error check  me thinks.